# Is there a way to specify location in string when using SQL REPLACE?

Tags: sql, replace

I am looking for something similar to

```
UPDATE table 
SET field = REPLACE(field, "findstring", "replacestring");
```

with a modifier for location.

I need to replace, for example:

Remove ",friday" from fields containing: `wednesday,thursday,friday`

While not changing fields containing: `thursday,friday,saturday`

And also, if possible, same situation with the needle at the beginning of the field.

Comment: so you only want to remove ",friday" from the end of the string OR remove "friday," from the beginning of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without a replace . . .

```
UPDATE table
SET field = (case when right(field, 7) = ',Friday'
                  then left(field, len(field) - 7)
                  else field
             end)


UPDATE table
SET field = (case when left(field, 7) = 'Friday,'
                  then right(field, len(field) - 7)
                  else field
             end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try the `SUBSTR` function?

Something like `SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, ',friday', -1)` This works in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This will work in Microsoft SQL Server.

```
UPDATE table 
SET field = REPLACE(field, 'friday', 'replacestring')
WHERE RIGHT(field, 6) = 'friday' 
   OR LEFT(field, 6) = 'friday'
```